# hyperopt Import error. unrecognized arguments: -f

Tags: python, machine-learning, importerror, hyperparameters, hyperopt

```
import hyperopt
usage: main.py [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]
main.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -f
inifile: None
rootdir: C:\Users\Myname
C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py:2889: UserWarning: To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.
warn("To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.", stacklevel=1)
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 2
```

This is the what I want to implement(import hyperopt) and following is the error on my jupyter console.

I am using anaconda 64bit 2.7.(windows 8)

I tried to install hyperopt with pip, conda and git, but all trials failed.
No error happened using when installing the packages.

Can you please let me know what is wrong with my laptop or hyperopt?
Thank you.

---

I also tried in the cmd python, I tried 'import hyperopt' but error below happend.

```
Python 2.7.13 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Dec 19 2016, 13:29:36)
```

[MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
    Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
    import hyperopt
    ============================= test session starts =============================
    platform win32 -- Python 2.7.13, pytest-3.0.5, py-1.4.32, pluggy-0.4.0
    rootdir: C:\Users\Seong NohYoon, inifile:
    collected 0 items / 1 errors

```
=================================== ERRORS ====================================
______________________________ ERROR collecting  ______________________________
C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\py\_path\common.py:366: in visit
    for x in Visitor(fil, rec, ignore, bf, sort).gen(self):
C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\py\_path\common.py:415: in gen
    for p in self.gen(subdir):
C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\py\_path\common.py:415: in gen
    for p in self.gen(subdir):
C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\py\_path\common.py:415: in gen
    for p in self.gen(subdir):
C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\py\_path\common.py:400: in gen
    entries = path.listdir()
C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\py\_path\local.py:382: in listdir
    names = py.error.checked_call(os.listdir, self.strpath)
C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\py\_error.py:85: in checked_call
    raise cls("%s%r" % (func.__name__, args))
E   EBUSY: [Resource device]: listdir('C:\\Users\\Seong NohYoon\\AppData\\Local\\Application Data',)
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 errors during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
=========================== 1 error in 0.30 seconds ===========================
```

Comment: please post the code you are trying to run

Comment: You should post the code as well as errors you are getting when installing the libraries.

Comment: the post contains the code and the error

Comment: I just did 'import hyperopt' and got the following error in the qtconsole.

Comment: I got no error when installing the libraries